# echo <tr> with a href inside not working

Tags: php, html

I'm pretty confused about the fact that I have this code:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo "<tr href='http://google.com'>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['rowname'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['rowname2'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['rowname3'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['rowname4'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
```

and for some reason my link doesn't work. I've tried putting `a` tag around the `tr` but with no success. Somebody to have a clue?

Comment: You means that you want to redirect?

Comment: `tr` tag has no attribute called `href`, use `onClick` javascript instead.

Comment: The `<tr>` tag defines a row; it has no attribute named `href`. What you probably meant was: `<td><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></td>`.

Comment: Thanks man. I tought to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you are looking for link to entire row. This can be achieved by having `onClick` function on the row, instead of using `href`.

```
<tr onClick="location.href='target url'">
   <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr onclick='window.location.href = \"http://google.com\";'>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['rowname'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['rowname2'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['rowname3'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['rowname4'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make entire row clickable and work like an `a` tag you should use javascript for this:

```
echo "<tr onclick='location.href = \"http://google.com\"'>";
```

And then it would be nice to add CSS cursor pointer to clickable table cells:

```
tr td {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a tr-tag has no href attribute, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp).

you can do something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    </td>
    ....
</tr>
```

Another Solution would be adding javascript if the whole row should be clickable:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href = google.com">
    <td>
       <a href="google.com"</a>
    </td>
    ....
</tr>
```